# SERV_MOD_ACT_TRACE_ENABLE problem

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, performance, trace, performance-tuning

```
SQL> EXECUTIVE DBMS_MONITOR.SERV_MOD_ACT_TRACE_ENABLE(service_name=>'ACC_SRV',waits=>TRUE,binds=>FALSE,instance_name=>'inst1');
```

Why this function need instance_name parameter?
I think the relations between instance and service are as follows(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/concepts.htm):

- One Service for one instance
- multi-services for one instance

If I call SERV_MOD_ACT_TRACE_ENABLE, a single trace file is created for each session that uses the ACC_SRV service. What effect is this instance parameter which is not null?

Comment: In Oracle RAC service can be run on multiple instances. If you provide the instance name then tracing is restricted to the specified instance name otherwise globally(all instances).

Comment: @JSapkota So there is a chance that one service for multi instances in RAC?

Comment: @shawn Yes, on a RAC it is possible to run a sevice on multiple instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the instance name, as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_monitor.htm#ARPLS67174)

> This procedure will enable SQL tracing for a given combination of
>   Service Name, MODULE and ACTION globally unless an instance_name is
>   specified.

instance_name has a default value null implicating it is not a required parameter. In a RAC database this would just enable tracing for your service in all open instances.